# d3.js: how to traverse back up the DOM

Tags: javascript, json, dom, d3.js

I'm not quite sure which aspect(s) of javascript, the DOM or d3.js this exposes my lack of knowledge of: just know that I am sorry to be asking such a basic question as the following. I'm new here.

I have a json like this:

```
[{"link":"a", "count": 3}, {"link":"b", "count": 4}, {"link":"c", "count": 2}]
```

and I'd like to make something that looks like

```
<ul>
    <li> <a>a</a> (3)</li>
    <li> <a>b</a> (4)</li>
    <li> <a>c</a> (2)</li>
</ul>
```

using d3.js (to address the obvious: I want to do a LOT more with d3, this just captures a problem I have).

After popping a `<ul>` tag in my html, somewhere in a callback from `d3.json` I can write something like this:

```
d3.select("ul")
    .selectAll("li")
    .data(json)
    .enter()
    .append("li")
    .append("a")
    .text(function(d){return d.link})
```

(though this is untested! how do javascript people test little scraps of code?). This will (probably) give me

```
<ul>
    <li><a>a</a></li>
    <li><a>b</a></li>
    <li><a>c</a></li>
</ul>
```

but now I can't get out of the `<a>` tag! I can't figure out what ungodly combination of `this` and selecting parents or whatnot I need to do to tack on that extra piece of information before the close of the list item tag. What do I need to do?

Comment: "how do javascript people test little scraps of code?" - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I don't know the d3 syntax I'm afraid, but could you not simply output d.count in the 'li' element before apending the 'a'? Thereby circumventing the need to traverse upward?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald wouldn't that put the d.count infront of the link instead of after it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple: don't go overboard with method chaining. :)

```
var ul = d3.select("ul");

var li = ul.selectAll("li")
    .data(json)
  .enter().append("li");

var a = li.append("a")
    .text(function(d) { return d.link; });
```

Now you can add other stuff to the li. In this case, since D3 only lets you add elements (rather than raw text nodes), you'll probably want to add a span for the parenthetical text:

```
li.append("span")
    .text(function(d) { return " (" + d.count + ")"; });
```

Comment: Thanks so much! for some reason that I'm not terribly sure of I'm trying to avoid variables at all costs. Will stop doing that.